# PHP / Web : Caching results of a db query for better page performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am trying to improve the load times of some pages on a website.

Each page consists of the same navigation headern section at the top, this header contains some metrics for the site, that is reloaded every time a user visits another page. The information in this header is quite dynamic but does not need to be updated more than about once every hour or so.

I would like to know how I might come upon a good solution for not reducing the number of db requests made by the page but at the same time not showing data in the nav header which is more than a couple of hours out of date.

Thanks

David

Comment: You just need to use a cache system as you said.

Comment: Can you give an example of how this might be done?

Comment: I think your question is currently too vague. You can find examples on the right of this page (look at the links in the "Related" section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a cache sytem as you said.

You can take a look at some sites such as [this](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php) or [this other one](http://www.xeweb.net/2010/01/15/simple-php-caching/).

I personally use the one offered by the framework I'm using. If you are using any framework its very likely that it has its own cache methods.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the way cache is handled, it seems to deal with complete pages. Ideally I would like to cache only the db results and request them from the page each time it is loaded (as the site is running in several languages and I think caching the whole page may give undesirable results) Do you know if there is a way to cache db results?

Comment: No. Cache can be done with anything else. If you just want to cache your query results. Save the array in a file and that's all. Is the same.

Comment: To anyone else reading this who is not familiar with cache, here is a sample piece of code that I wrote to start off: